# Can I default a sql stored procedure parameter to a dynamic expression?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, dynamic, default

I want to have a "@myDate" parameter in a stored procedure that defaults to 2 years prior to today if nothing else is specified. I tried doing something like this in my procedure definition:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE myProcedure(   @param1 int,
                                @param2 varchar(20),
                                @param3 int = null,
                                @myDate datetime = dateadd(year,-2,getDate()) )
```

I'm getting the following syntax error:

```
Incorrect syntax near '('.
```

Does sql server allow you to set dynamic expressions as default parameter values? If not, how can I get around this (other than the clumsy `IF @myDate is null SET @myDate=...`)?

Comment: There is a fine line between clumsy and lazy.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't use an expression as default value, and there is no really elegant way of doing this.

You can use `isnull` or  `coalesce` instead of the `if` statement:

```
set @myDate = isnull(@myDate, dateadd(year, -2, getdate()))
```

Answer (score 1):

No.

From the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx):

> The default value must be a constant
>   or it can be NULL